# How to execute the threads in JMeter to full fill the below scenario?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a JMeter work flow where in the script has to perform the below scenario.

1. There are 130 users and 29000 tasks.
2. Ideally, 1 user takes approx. 2min to perform 1 task by sending JSON requests.
3. After completing one task then only, the current user has to pick the other task.
4. Can you please help me, how to achieve this in the thread group or anything needs to be added here.

Right now, I have added the `USER`, `PASS`,`TaskID` under the `PackingTasksCSVConfig`

Kindly help me to pass the correct values for the **Thread Properties** so that, 130 Users can perform 29000 requests accordingly.[image: JMETER-SNIPPET]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

   - set "Number of threads" to `130`
   - set "Number of Loops`to 224 (or tick`Infinite`)
2. Supply sufficient data for 29000 requests in the CSV file
3. In the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

   - configure it to read the file from step 2
   - if you set number of loops in Thread Group to `infinite` make sure to set `Stop Thread on EOF` to `True`
4. If JMeter executes actions for performing the tasks in less than 2 minutes you will need to slow it down using [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) or [implement Pacing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter)